# What is the expected value of modified Dirichlet distribution? (integration problem)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

It is easy to produce a random variable with Dirichlet distribution using Gamma variables with the same scale parameter. If:

$ X_i \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha_i, \beta) $

Then:

$ \left(\frac{X_1}{\sum_j X_j},\; \ldots\; , \frac{X_n}{\sum_j X_j}\right) \sim \text{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\;\ldots\;,\alpha_n) $

*Problem*
What happens if the scale parameters are not equal?

$ X_i \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha_i, \beta_i) $

Then what is the distribution this variable?

$ \left(\frac{X_1}{\sum_j X_j},\; \ldots\; , \frac{X_n}{\sum_j X_j}\right) \sim \; ? $

For me it would be sufficient to know the expected value of this distribution.
I need a approximate closed algebraic formula that can be evaluated very very quickly by a computer.
Let's say approximation with accurancy of 0.01 is sufficient.
You can assume that:

$ \alpha_i, \beta_i \in \mathbb{N} $

*Note* In short, the task is to find an approximation of this integral:

$ f(\vec{\alpha}, \vec{\beta}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n_+} \;\frac{x_1}{\sum_j x_j} \cdot \prod_j \frac{\beta_j^{\alpha_j}}{\Gamma(\alpha_j)} x_j^{\alpha_j - 1} e^{-\beta_j x_j} \;\;  dx_1\ldots dx_n$

Comment: You can find a relatively simple expression for the pdf of $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ on p. 3 in http://web.njit.edu/~abdi/gamma.pdf

Comment: Also, that pdf in the case of integer shape parameters is obtained in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WK9-45J4Y1R-19&_user=10&_coverDate=01%2F31%2F1998&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1633430810&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=d77d3824d69fbdee236d45bb49a7f9a0&searchtype=a

Comment: It is well known that sum of Gammas is a Gamma distributed as well, but it doesn't hel here

Comment: $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is Gamma distributed if all the scale parameters are equal.

Comment: Indeed. Anyway the distribution of sum doesn't help as it is correlated with $X_1$

Comment: It might help in general, since you can condition on the sum $X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ (which is independent of $X_1$). I agree that this is not likely to help you much, but it was only a comment...

Comment: Good point. I will work with it.